# React secure environment variables on production build

Tags: reactjs, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, yarnpkg

I am building a React app and using Docker and Jenkins for production deployment... How can I provide environment variables securely to this static app? 
This is my Dockerfile:

```
# stage 1: build the react app
FROM node:10.15.0 as react-build

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

ARG REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT
ARG REACT_APP_CONNECT_URI
ARG REACT_APP_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID
ARG REACT_APP_CONNECT_SECRET
ARG REACT_APP_CONNECT_CALLBACK_URL

RUN yarn
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT=${REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT}
ENV REACT_APP_CONNECT_URI=${REACT_APP_CONNECT_URI}
ENV REACT_APP_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID=${REACT_APP_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID}
ENV REACT_APP_CONNECT_SECRET=${REACT_APP_CONNECT_SECRET}
ENV REACT_APP_CONNECT_CALLBACK_URL=${REACT_APP_CONNECT_CALLBACK_URL}
RUN yarn run -s build

# Stage 2: build the production environment
FROM openresty/openresty:alpine
COPY deploy/files/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=react-build /app /usr/local/openresty/nginx/html

# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/access.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/error.log

EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

At the moment the build process makes those vars exposed :(

Comment: Why do you use some secret variables in client app like React?

Comment: Because I need to connect to an API that requires it. What is the best practice to secure those vars?

Comment: Do you have backend application to connect to the API? Normally, when you connect to an API you need connect at backend side and you can protect your secret vars.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to use a **.env** file to load your environment variables during the build process (eg in webkpack with the DefinePlugin).

Then you just `RUN yarn run -s build` without having to specify each separate env variable.

There's even a shortcut npm package for your webpack setup. [webpack-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack)

Comment: Thanks but this also exposes the variables once the build is done.

Comment: @numediaweb you can't hide any env variables. If the build needs them you can't hide them

Comment: I see, so I guess I need a backend server... Strange that nothing like that is mentioned on the React docs: I mean, most apps need some kind of env variables for at least dev/staging/production env...

Comment: @numediaweb React is a library. It does not concern them what you do with it. Any env variables are used through JS environment and whatever build process you use. You might not even run webpack. So it does not concern React at all